# İ did a notification page and want to do slide delete system. how can i do that?

Tags: react-native

```
 Card = ({ product }: { product: any }) => (
<View style={{marginTop:20}}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <Image source={product.img}></Image>
    <View style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
      <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"#8a8c8f"}}>
        {product.name}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ color:"#b6b7b9"}}>
      {"  "} {product.time}
      </Text>
      </View>
      {product.follower > 0 ? 
      <View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"#8a8c8f"}}>{product.name}</Text>
          <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"#b6b7b9"}}>{""} ve {""}</Text>
          <Text  style={{fontWeight:"bold", color:"#8a8c8f"}}>{product.follower}</Text>
          <Text  style={{color:"#b6b7b9"}}>{""} kişi resmine oy verdi{""}</Text>
          
        </View>
      </View> :
      <Text  style={{color:"#b6b7b9"}}>
        {product.command}
      </Text> 
    }
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

this is my card and:

```
 <FlatList
          style={{ margin: 10, width: "100%" }}
          numColumns={1}
          data={products}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <this.Card product={item} />}

        />
```

this is flat list. can anybody tell me how can i add slide delete to this? I dont know how to do. need some help
waiting for messages

Answer (score 0):

try using [react-native-swipe-list-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-list-view)

Check the [example](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/blob/master/SwipeListExample/examples/swipe_to_delete.js). I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i saw it but its using number. i need that using json data

Comment: i getting always this error: Parameter 'swipeData' implicitly has an 'any' type.